# woocommerce display tag description on product page

Tags: woocommerce, tags, display

I looked around for a while today for a way to display a tag description on the product page. But could not find a close answer to my issue of displaying a tag description.

I know if you have more than one tag on a page and it pulls in all tag descriptions would not be good for SEO or page look but I believe we are only pulling in one tag that contains a description, the rest are generic tags without a description.

Where should I be looking at how this can be done?  I'm sure this is a common woocommerce mod and I'm not using the correct woocommerce terminology. Here is the info currently being displayed on our product page.
----current----
**Tag - Rose Quartz**

----desired-----
**Tag - Rose Quartz**

> This beautiful pink stone is well-known for the loving powers that it
>   gives off. This is the stone of love, but more crystal experts see it
>   as self-love, self-esteem, and acceptance of one’s true self. Rose
>   quartz also helps to ward off any resentment that the wearer has in
>   their lives that have built up over time. This stone brings strength to
>   the heart.

Comment: So I figured out how this can be done and would like to share my findings.  You will need to first have a way to add snippets to your page. I used a plugin called

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how this can be done and would like to share my findings.  You will need to first have a way to add snippets to your page. I used a plugin called XYZ PHP Code, this plugin allows me to create PHP snippets to be used in elementor page builder.

I created a new snippet in XYZ named "tagdesc" and used the following code to display tag descriptions.

```html
<?php
$posttags = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $product_tag) {
        echo $product_tag->name; 
        echo $product_tag->description;
    }
}
?>
```

Save and use your snippet in my case it was called [xyz-ips snippet="tagdesc"].

This will display all the tag names and descriptions of that product. In my case I removed (echo $product_tag->name;) as I did not need to show the tag name. This works in our case as only one tag has a description, I feel a better solution would be pulling out a description from a single product attribute using a similar method but have not found a solution that works.